# jquery escaping square brackets in array

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parsing, escaping, shortcode

i am trying to parse wordpress shortcodes with square brackets

```
            <script src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <style>


            </style>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="6" id="editor">
            [section] content [/section]
            </textarea>
            <div id="display"></div>

            <script>
            var fr = {
                "\\[section\\]": "<div class'section'>",
                "[/section]": "</div>",
                "content": "new content",
            };

            var re = $.map(fr, function (v, k) {
                return {
                    regex: new RegExp('\\b' + k + '\\b', 'g'),
                    value: v
                };
            });


            $("#editor").keyup(function(){
                        var post = $("#editor").val();
                        $('#display').html(post);
                        parse();
            });


            function parse()
            {
                    jQuery('#display').html(function (i, val) {
                    $.each(re, function (i, obj) {
                        val = val.replace(obj.regex, obj.value);
                    });
                    return val;
                });
            }

            $("#editor").keyup();

            </script>
```

i have tried escaping the brackets with  double \ but no effect is there a way to escape them or alternatively a different way to parse them altogether

Comment: Note that Wordpress is in noConflict mode by default, and the native editor is TinyMCE, which should have hooks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your slashes are /, they should be \ for escaping. Writing `"\[stuff\]"` should be just fine.

Comment: thanks for that but it is not matching the escaped strings any ideas?